# Online tool for writing notes with Wikipedia syntax?

Tags: web-apps, editor

Are there some websites where I could write and save some notes written using Wikipedia syntax. In particular, I would like if it would be easy to link to Wikipedia articles just by writing things like `[[Wikipedia]]`. (I.e., in the same way as when you edit Wikipedia article.)

(Something combining MarkDown syntax with simpler way of linking to Wikipedia would be of interest for me, too.)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that you are looking for is called [MediaWiki Markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki#Markup), *wiki is where the name Wikipedia comes from - a wiki that is encyclopaedic and [MediaWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) is the specific software used for Wikipedia*, and there are literally hundreds of sites that you can use to host your own wiki and thousands that have active wikis that you can to a greater or lesser degree contribute to.

Within any wiki that is based on [MediaWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki), *(the syntax and availability will vary on other wiki platforms)*, it is possible to use the **[InterWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki) syntax** to specify links to other, predefined, wikis. In this case a link such as:

```
[[Wikipedia:Main Page]]
```

Would appear as [Wikipedia:Main Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) and would take you to the Wikipedia main page. So you just need to use, *or host*, one of the wikis based on MediaWiki that has Wikipedia defined as an InterWiki target or find the equivalent syntax on other wiki hosts.

Comment: Yes, I know what wiki is and that it is possible to create a new wiki site. (Either on some wiki-hosting site or my own installation.) It is not exactly what I am looking for; but perhaps still close. However, still the thing is that by writing something like `[[Wikipedia]]` on such wiki, it would produce a link to something like `http://mysite/wiki/Wikipedia` rather than `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia`, which is what I would like to have. (I.e., I am looking for some tool to write texts which will include links to Wikipedia, without entering each link in the full length.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak - I think I have addressed what you are looking for in an edit.

Comment: I do not think the claim that "*wiki syntax* is where the name Wikipedia comes from" is correct. In particular, Wikipedia, and the underlying MediaWiki, came long after the first wiki.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia second paragraph: "Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger launched Wikipedia on January 15, 2001. Sanger coined its name, a portmanteau of __wiki__ and encyclopedia. "

Comment: @SteveBarnes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki#History first paragraph: "*WikiWikiWeb* was the first wiki.[11] Ward Cunningham started developing WikiWikiWeb (...) in 1994, and installed it on the Internet domain c2.com on March 25, 1995. It was named by Cunningham, who remembered a Honolulu International Airport counter employee telling him to take the 'Wiki Wiki Shuttle' bus". Also, note 3 in the text you are citing says that *wiki* is a type of website. That is, the type of user-editable website *and* its name *wiki* were both there by the time WP and its syntax came to life.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I did say that Wikipedia __got its name from__ the fact that it was a wiki and used a wiki syntax so of course the wiki came __before__ Wikipedia - hence trying to point out to the OP that he was looking for a (media)wiki syntax __not__ a Wikipedia syntax. So the statement that the name Wikipedia came __from__ the fact that it was a wiki and used a wiki syntax is quite correct.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: I see - when reading the answer, I cannot help seeing "Wiki syntax, this is where the name Wikipedia comes from" as a statement there, although you probably meant the sentence to be parsed differently. In any case, the OP explicitly mentions "Wikipedia syntax" and "MarkDown syntax", which at least seems like they are fully aware there are various syntaxes used in wikis, but they are specifically looking for the particular syntax used in Wikipedia (i.e. the one from Mediawiki) first and foremost, with other syntaxes being "of interest (...), too".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper exactly "this is where the name __Wikipedia__ comes from" you seem to be under the impression that I was saying that the name wiki came from Wikipedia which is the exact opposite of what I said.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: No, I am under the impression that the answer can be read as saying that the name *Wikipedia* (and possibly the name *wiki* itself) comes from the term *wiki syntax*, as *wiki syntax* is the term the answer starts with.